# How to get trailing data of LZMA archive?

Tags: file-format, lzma

Similar to [How to get trailing data of gzip archive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295702/how-to-get-trailing-data-of-gzip-archive) for GZIP archives I need a way to get the trailing data of an LZMA archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the solution posted in the GZIP thread, I created a Perl script to get the data. Note that this one uses a Perl module which isn't installed per default and in my case required another module and the sources for LZMA encoding/decoding, so I had to do the following on my Ubuntu 16.04 server first:

```sh
sudo apt install -y liblzma-dev
sudo cpan Compress::Raw::Lzma
sudo cpan IO::Uncompress::UnLzma
```

The Perl script:

```pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

use IO::Uncompress::UnLzma qw(:all);
use IO::File;

my $in = new IO::File "<-" or die "Input error!\n";
unlzma $in => "/dev/null",
  TrailingData => my $trailing;
undef $in;

print $trailing;
```

Usage:

```sh
./lzmaTrailingDataGet.pl </path/to/input.lzma >/path/to/output.bin
```